# Keeping null value after json.load() in Python

Tags: python, json

I loaded a JSON file through `json.load(file)` and edited it.
I want to send a requests with `json=payload` that has some `null` values. But, after loading it in python, it became `"None"`.

My question is how do I keeping `null` and without converting to `"None"` to send the requests.

Example:
Before `json.loads()`

```
{
  "key1": 10,
  "key2": "Comes and Goes",
  "key3": null,
  "key4": null,
  "key5": null,
  "key6": []
}
```

After `json.load()`

```
{
  "key1": 10,
  "key2": "Comes and Goes",
  "key3": None,
  "key4": None,
  "key5": None,
  "key6": []
}
```

But what I really want after `json.load()` is:

```
{
  "key1": 10,
  "key2": "Comes and Goes",
  "key3": null,
  "key4": null,
  "key5": null,
  "key6": []    
}
```

Any help is appreciatted! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Python's `json.loads()` shouldn't _ever_ translate `null` to `"None"`; it should only translate it to `None` **without the quotes**, which is how Python writes the value that JavaScript calls `null`. Can you show the specific code you're using to invoke `loads()`, so we can cause this problem ourselves?

Comment: @J-Coder a small snippet of working code will provide more clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `json.load` you are **converting** the JSON object into a Python object. I.e. JSON objects are converted into dicts, JSON arrays into Python lists, etc.

Python's `null` value is `None`, and that's the conversion you should expect. When you convert it back using `json.dump`, you'll get the same `null`-s back.

Consider this small snippet:

```
with open('in.json') as fin:
    data = json.load(fin)

print(data) # Print Python object
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4)) # Print output JSON
```

If the contents of `in.json` are:

```
{
    "key1": 10,
    "key2": "Comes and Goes",
    "key3": null,
    "key4": null,
    "key5": null,
    "key6": []
}
```

Printing the Python object results in:

```
{'key1': 10, 'key2': 'Comes and Goes', 'key3': None, 'key4': None, 'key5': None, 'key6': []}
```

And printing the `json.dumps` result in the exact same content as the input file:

```
{
    "key1": 10,
    "key2": "Comes and Goes",
    "key3": null,
    "key4": null,
    "key5": null,
    "key6": []
}
```

Comment: I should have know that, thank you!